Unable to bind this Intro Activity, I tried this but it's only showing "Hello World"
This is the IntroActivity code:
package com.example.drappointment

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.drappointment.databinding.ActivityIntroBinding

class IntroActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityIntroBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityIntroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.startBtn.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@IntroActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}

And this is the activity_intro.xml layout file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IntroActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Exceptional Care\nClose To You"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/intro_image_description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/intro_women"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_halo" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/purple_bg"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/white_arrow"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Get Started"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Gradle Version
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip

View Binding Configuration
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}



try to clean build and rebuild the project also check if  build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out directory to see if your ActivityIntroBinding is correctly generated

@AhmadAl-Sanie the ActivityIntroBinding is generated in build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/example/projectname/ActivityIntryBinding.java,

AndroidManifest.xml
After two days of debugging, I finally pinpointed the issue to the AndroidManifest.xml file. The problem was that the IntroActivity was not being recognized as the launcher activity, which was causing the application to default to showing "Hello World" and not navigating to the MainActivity.
Original AndroidManifest.xml Configuration
Before making any changes, my AndroidManifest.xml file was configured as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DrAppointment"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

In this configuration:

IntroActivity was missing the android:exported="true" attribute.
MainActivity was correctly set up with the android:exported="true" attribute and the intent-filter to launch the app.

Updated AndroidManifest.xml Configuration
Here’s the corrected configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DrAppointment"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>

Key Changes:

Added android:exported="true" to IntroActivity to make it available for launching.
Ensured IntroActivity had an intent-filter to define it as the main entry point of the application.

By making these changes, the IntroActivity is now properly set up as the launcher activity, and the application correctly navigates to MainActivity upon clicking the button.
If you are facing similar issues, make sure that your AndroidManifest.xml includes all necessary attributes and configurations for your activities, especially the android:exported attribute for components intended to be launched.

Feel free to adjust any details to better fit your experience or the specifics of your problem!
